# VS 2017 Error TS1219

Tags: json, visual-studio, typescript, webpack, configuration

After changing the architecture of my UI project I got so many errors(TS1219 and TS2304). Is the reason is bad configuring tsconfig.json?Or something else?
If I remove decorators from the project all is okay but I need them.
I use Visual Studio 2017, ASP.CORE 2.1 template for angular 5.

Error   TS1219  (TS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

tsconfig.json:

```
    {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: settings]

If you need more information let me know.

**UPD: Errors with @NgModule in the app.module do not appear**
The errors appear when I wrap ts files with decorators into folders.
Does it not work with files with a large depth?

You can see folder tree on my [bitbucket(BooksRework branch)](https://bitbucket.org/Perdywok/libraryangularapp/src/booksRework/).

Comment: The question is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Build Action` value of the `*.ts` file which causes an error. It should be `None`, not `TypeScript File`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer resolved it for me.  I used Visual Studio to add "TypeScript File" which set the `Build Action` automatically.  Switching this back to `None` (like my other TypeScript files already were) resolved the error.